# By definition prove if a sequence is Cauchy

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

I am going to prove $a_n=\dfrac{n^2}{2n^2+3}$ is Cauchy.

This is what I did:

Let $\epsilon>0$.

$|a_n-a_m|=\dfrac{3}{4}.\dfrac{n^2+m^2}{n^2 m^2}<\dfrac{n^2+m^2}{n^2 m^2}=\dfrac{1}{m^2}+\dfrac{1}{n^2}$
 $m,n$ are index of sequence elements.
My question is : Am I allowed to conclude $\dfrac{1}{m^2}+\dfrac{1}{n^2}<\dfrac{1}{m}+\dfrac{1}{n}$
I mean are $m,n$ always considered to be positive integers? so that as the last part of the proof can I state:

for the given $\epsilon>0$ we choose an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t $N>\dfrac{2}{\epsilon}$.
Then for all $n,m\ge N$, We have 
$|a_n-a_m|<\dfrac{1}{n^2}+\dfrac{1}{m^2}<\dfrac{1}{N}+\dfrac{1}{N}=\dfrac{2}{N}<\epsilon$

Does this sound correct to you? What do you recomment to prove the sequence above is Cauchy?

Comment: Looks good to me

Comment: Your identity for $|a_n-a_m|$ seems incorrect; perhaps you want an inequality? In any case, yes, $m$ and $n$ are positive integers because they are indices of a sequence. On the other hand, you can also choose $N > \sqrt{2/\epsilon}$ and thereby bypass the inequality you're asking about.

Comment: Thank you Very Much